# Deprecation - The website requested a subresource from a network that it could only access because of its users' privileged network position

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, vuejs3, vue-cli

How to disable the following warning in Chrome devtool's console?

> [Deprecation] The website requested a subresource from a network that it could only access because of its users' privileged network position. These requests expose non-public devices and servers to the internet, increasing the risk of a cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack, and/or information leakage. To mitigate these risks, Chrome deprecates requests to non-public subresources when initiated from non-secure contexts, and will start blocking them in Chrome 92 (July 2021). See https://chromestatus.com/feature/5436853517811712 for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the Vue CLI, when the app starts, the following was printed in the terminal:

```
App running at:

- Local: http://localhost:8080/
- Network: http://192.168.100.100:8080/
```

And I was using the `Network` one and got the warning, changed to use the `Local` URL removed the warning for me.